# What is the smallest combination for Aurora? - RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

I have this error when creating `RDS`.

I want to make the smallest RDS for `Aurora`.

```
RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.micro, Engine=aurora-mysql, EngineVersion=5.7.mysql_
aurora.2.08.1, LicenseModel=general-public-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation. (
Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: ffe9ac1f-aecf-4c20-8525-51684b1457ef; Proxy: null)
```

I use `ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2` and `ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO` with for `rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_08_1`

What is the smallest conbination for amazon aurora??

```
let instanceType = ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO);
const dbCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'Database', {
  parameterGroup,
  engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({ version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_08_1 }),
  credentials: rdsCredentials,
  cloudwatchLogsExports:['slowquery','general','error','audit'],
  backup: backupProps,
  instances:instances,
  s3ExportBuckets: s3ExportBuckets,
  storageEncrypted:true,
  storageEncryptionKey:rdsKmsKey,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  clusterIdentifier: dbInfos['cluster'], //clusterIdentifier,
  defaultDatabaseName :dbInfos['database'], //defaultDatabaseName,
  instanceProps: {
    instanceType: instanceType,
    vpcSubnets:resourceName.subnet_ids(vpc,this,'rds'),
    vpc,
    securityGroups:[dbSecurityGroup],
  },
  subnetGroup:subnetGroup
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t3.small` is the smallest AWS Aurora MySQL instance size currently supported. Please see the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/).

In the CDK that would be `BURSTABLE3` and `SMALL`.

Comment: Thank you very much I understood I will use mysql instead of Aurora